# How do I access only specific colums of the summary() output?

Tags: r, dataframe

Essentially what I want to do is only use the `summary()` function in `r` only on specific columns of my df.

Basically doing this (using the cars df as an example):

```
cars_summary <- summary(cars)
speed_summary <- cars_summary$speed
```

When I try to do this I get an error saying:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What does that mean and is there a way to do this without `sapply()`?

Thanks!

Comment: If you look at (for example) `dimnames(summary(cars))`, you'll see that `"    speed"` is in the second-dim, but it has added spaces, making it not really intended to be captured that way (spaced/indented solely for aesthetics). You could instead do `summary(cars$speed)` and get right to the stats you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front, I think you can do just `summary(cars$speed)` to get what you want.

```r
summary(cars$speed)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0
```

If you will want this for multiple columns, and `speed` is just one example, then try this:

```r
cars_summary <- lapply(cars, summary)
cars_summary$speed
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#     4.0    12.0    15.0    15.4    19.0    25.0
```

---

However, there are some other things going on.

1. The column names of the summary matrix are buffered/padded so that the names appear to be centered over the stats. This is purely aesthetic, but they do make it a little unpredictable (well, not-easy) to capture.

   ```r
   cars_summary <- summary(cars)
   dimnames(cars_summary)
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
   # [[2]]
   # [1] "    speed" "     dist"
   ```
2. It's a `matrix`, so you cannot use `$`-indexing on it. One would instead need to use `[,"speed"]` or whatever.

   ```r
   cars_summary[,"    speed"]
   #                                                                                                       
   # "Min.   : 4.0  " "1st Qu.:12.0  " "Median :15.0  " "Mean   :15.4  " "3rd Qu.:19.0  " "Max.   :25.0  " 

   ### or perhaps
   colnames(cars_summary) <- names(cars)
   cars_summary[,"speed"]
   #                                                                                                       
   # "Min.   : 4.0  " "1st Qu.:12.0  " "Median :15.0  " "Mean   :15.4  " "3rd Qu.:19.0  " "Max.   :25.0  "
   ```
3. Hrrmmm, it's a matrix, but it's a matrix of *strings*, as you can see above and here:

   ```r
   ### back to the original cars_summary
   str(cars_summary)
   #  'table' chr [1:6, 1:2] "Min.   : 4.0  " "1st Qu.:12.0  " "Median :15.0  " "Mean   :15.4  " "3rd Qu.:19.0  " "Max.   :25.0  " ...
   #  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
   #   ..$ : chr [1:6] "" "" "" "" ...
   #   ..$ : chr [1:2] "    speed" "     dist"
   ```

   While one *could* certainly use some patterns or such to extract those numbers, there *will* be loss of precision/accuracy.